# how to select a radio button by default - asp.net mvc strongly typed html helpers

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have a radio button list like this:

```
<%=Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Gender,"Male")%>
```

I want this button selected by default. How do I do this?

Answer (score 20):

```
<%: Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Gender, "Male", new { @checked = "checked" }) %>
```

or in the controller action that renders this view:

```
model.Gender = "Male";
return View(model);
```

Comment: Sorry Darin, This is not working. Is there any alternate solution ?

Comment: Sure it is working, I've just created a sample ASP.MVC project, put a view model with a single property `Gender` (of type string), and in the view used HTML attributes to set the `checked` property.

Answer (score 6):

**if u are using Razor view strong you can use use radio button like this**

```
  @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.PrintOrder, "Sequential", new {@checked="true"})    Sequential
```

as your need correct it as
Razor view

```
  @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Gender, "Male", new { @checked = "checked" })
```

Aspx view

```
  <%: Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Gender, "Male", new { @checked = "checked" }) %>
```

Comment: not working dude

Answer (score 3):

TRY:

```
<%: Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Gender, "Male", new { Checked = true }) %>
```

Worked in my case.