# How can i sort and display <IList> elements in radio button?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, list, razor

I have data `IList<String>` type in my Model returning string date in `yyyyMM` format, I need help to display array elements in radio button sorted descending order in `MM/yyyy` format.

My Model look like as follows:

```
 public class DataToLoad
 {
        public List<string> Months{ get; set; }       
 }
```

In my view I have the following to display array element in radio button.

```
foreach (var record in Model.Months)
{
  <div class="radio col-12">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-5" style="">
         @Html.RadioButton("Months", record, true, new { id = record, @class = "m-r" })<label>@record</label>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
}
```

I need if `Months` return 199008 and 19909, I want to sort values descending and format as MM/yyyy and display the values using radio button `09/1990 first then 08/1990`. Any Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
foreach (var record in Model.Months.Select(x=>$"{x.Substring(4,2)}/{x.Substring(0,4)}").OrderByDescending(x=>x))
{
     <div class="radio col-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-5" style="">
            @Html.RadioButton("Months", record, true, new { id = record, @class = "m-r" })<label>@record</label>
           </div>
         </div>
      </div>
}
```

Comment: Thank you that works Perfect!, Is there any way to select the oldest date  by default? for example if dates are `199008 and 19909` by default 08/1990 radio button auto selected?. Right now when order desc selects the old date as a default order ascending selects the recent date

Comment: @kukamuk you are welcome. Of course after order by descending, the last item on the list is the oldest date. If you could use for instead of foreach, if you checked = "true" for the case where i == Model.Months.Count()-1, the default will be selected. For more information about checked https://stackoverflow.com/a/18010222/8810311

Comment: Thanks Ramil!. `where i == Model.Months.Count()-1` using `foreach`?

Answer (score 1):

Same as any other piece of C# code, use Linq:

```
   @foreach (var record in Model.Months.OrderBy(x => x))
   {
     <div class="radio col-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-5" style="">
            @Html.RadioButton("Months", record, true, new { id = record, @class = "m-r" })<label>@record</label>
           </div>
         </div>
      </div>
    }
```

Comment: Thank you!! yes that work but how can i format string as `MM/yyyy` format and auto select the first one currently display as yyyyMM?

Comment: In the label I assume? Again, same as any other C# date formatting code: `<label>@record.ToString("yyyyMM")</label>`

Comment: Oh I just noticed they're actual strings, in that case you want to make it a `DateTime` first (you should actually only use `DateTime`, never strings): <label>@DateTime.ParseExact(record, "MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyyMM")</label>